# Joining two tables from one form

Tags: sql, vb.net, forms, join

I am completely lost.  I am working on a new project, a task manager.  The goal is to add users (working fine), then add tasks to the users.  Keep in mind I am doing this only with information I can find and teaching myself.

I have 2 SQL tables.  user and Task (case sensitive).

user has UserID, Name, PayPalEmail, and GeneralEmail.

Task has Name, OrderNumber, WordCount, Amount, DateDue, TimeDue, AM, PM, myDateDue, myTimeDue, MY_AM, MY_PM, and Task.

I have searched for a couple days now about how to join the tables together so I can choose a name and add a task to them inside text boxes AND query the name and have all of the tasks assigned to them show in the same text boxes.

At the risk of sounding lazy, can someone either show me the code, give me a easy to understand tutorial or something that is easy to follow so I can learn it myself.

Comment: `Task` should have a foreign key of `User` table.

Comment: You will need something that relates the two tables together. Is the task related to a user? If so the Task should include the User ID.

Answer (score 2):

user has UserID, Name, PayPalEmail, and GeneralEmail.

Task has **UserID**, Name, OrderNumber, WordCount, Amount, DateDue, TimeDue, AM, PM, myDateDue, myTimeDue, MY_AM, MY_PM, and Task.(You'll need to add UserID as the foreign key)

assuming the table Task has UserID as a foreign key, pointing to user table:

`select user.UserID, user.Name, user.PaypalEmail, Task.Name, Task.OrderNo from user inner join Task on user.UserID=Task.UserID group by user.Name`

Comment: When I do this in Query builder, I get the result: "The schema returned by the new query differs from the base query".  I have tried just about every single combination I can think of and it still gives me the same result.  I double checked and the query is exactly what is written above and nothing.

Comment: did you create UserID inside Task? @Andrew

Comment: Yes, there is a UserID in both, both are int and identity specific.

Comment: @Andrew: Try surrounding your fields with `[]`'s - `[user].[userid]`; some versions of SQL may kick off a little with this.  Also, only the primary key in your User table should be an identity field; the userid field in your other table is a foreign key.